# Shared class or memory over IIS worker process in NUMA web garden

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-core

I have website written in .Net Core at this time we have many visitor and I want to use web garden and increase performance because at peak time site become to slow.

The problem with multi core worker processor is :
I have class that check payment from the bank some time the the user send multiple time the request and one of the request use WP1 and second one go into WP2 and both run same function at same time and the account balance increased 2 time or more.

This could happen in single process also but I make shared class that control each user do not run 1 web API post per session (It is important user do not run multiple post with their account at same time)

Question: 
How I could use this shared class along all worker process instant or any other shared memory in IIS that I could use it to put string or serialized data inside them. I do not want use sql server because its slower than memory and it could not help me in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not easy out of the box solution for that.

What options you have to share data among different worked process.

Database
Common file / File Database
File Mapping / shared Memory
Make a service and communicate with it.

More to read :

[Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications#using-data-copy-for-ipc)
[Pipe Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipe-operations)
[WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/ms735119(v=vs.90))

Comment: Just list of user that currently in the post controller and after it remove from the list

Comment: @MasterProgrammer Its sounds simple - but its not - months of work on similar problems to have the maximum speed, and the same memory on different process

Comment: in addition I must say that the whole server is for us and we can make console application on it to make server for this part. Now I'm thinking about pipe or socket programming what do you think about this one https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/IPC-in-net-core-using-protobuf/

Comment: @MasterProgrammer I user protobuf, its made on c# by one of the stackoverflow programmers - its very fast serialize/deserialize protocol. Still is a data exchange - its even faster if you use just a file database, even just a file binary read write

Comment: Thank you, I use socket programming and made socket server and putt all classes inside socket server and just send and receive between worker process now I could use NUMA without any risk